# Apriori Algorithm on bigger dataset

Tags: r, apriori

I have this sample Dataset look like this:
[image]

I wrote this code in R to run Apriori Algorithm on it:

```
df_itemList<- read.csv('data.3.txt')
write.csv(df_itemList,"ItemList.csv", row.names = TRUE)

txn = read.transactions(file="ItemList.csv", rm.duplicates= TRUE, format="basket",sep=",",cols=1);

basket_rules <- apriori(txn,parameter = list(sup = 0.01, conf = 0.5,target="rules"));

df_basket <- as(basket_rules,"data.frame") 
write.csv(df_basket,"ItemList2.csv", row.names = TRUE)
```

the code works very good and it gives me rules as expected, but when I run it on the real dataset "2000 rows" it executes in few second and gives just 4 trivial rules

Comment: have you tries altering the support and/or confidence?

Comment: @user20650 they are already too small, and I am sure that the program does not execute, because it gives the result in milliseconds